# How to connect to a device within my network but connected to another router

Tags: networking, router, nas

I have a main router, which is connected to my ISP. Then, I have two sub-routers and a NAS-server attached to my main router. See image below:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UaOU.png)

**Problem:**

I cannot access any other device in my network, unless connected to the same router.

**What I would like:**

I would like to be able to access my other devices from any PC in my network (especially be able to access my NAS from any PC).

**Conditions:**

With my main router, it is not possible to put it into bridge mode. I have e-mailed my ISP about this, and they also told me there was no way I could put it in the bridge mode.

Secondly, I fear that my NAS will be accessible from the internet, which obviously is not what I want.

**My gear:**

- Unknown type Cisco main router
- Cisco linksys WRT54G router
- Cisco linksys E4200 v2 router
- Synology DS411J network attached storage(NAS), attached to my main router
- One windows 8.1 pc, attached to my WRT54G
- One windows 7 pc, attached to my E4200 v2

**Question:**

What could I possibly do/What settings should I adjust to make it work?

Comment: Why do you actually use the two routers (Linksys)?

Comment: I use one for upstairs and one for downstairs, otherwise there would be a mess of cables. However, I could move the NAS, if that would facilitate the problem.

Comment: I see this as the problem (using the two routers). Every router has it's own subnet: The unknows Cisco router has address for example 192.168.0.* , the first Linksys has 192.168.1.* and the second has 192.168.2.* . Try changing the modes of Linskyses to Access point only.

Comment: Please forgive me for asking, but how can I access my NAS from my pc,  for example, after I have done this?

Comment: How do you access your NAS from your PC? Do you enter it's IP address into the address bar in web browser? Or how?

Comment: Nevermind, I do understand it now and it does work, thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here is your biggest problem. When you use a home router to deal with your network you are using something called NAT (Network Address Translation) the point of this is so that it acts as a firewall. This is most likely the cause of your issue. You need to make sure you setup your network like the following:

Main router setup with DHCP turned on so clients can get IP addresses. When you plug from your main router to your secondary routers you MUST plug into the LAN side of the router (the 4-5 ports side of the router) which will turn the router into a switch... DO NOT I repeat DO NOT plug into the WAN port or else you are creating a firewall between your networks. You would then disable DHCP on both your secondary routers. You can still use the WiFi on either of the two routers past the main one and it will work like it should. This is because all your computers are now in a big switched environment instead of a NATed environment. They will all get IPs from your main router and everything should be able to communicate.